# React frontend + WordPress API create/register user with frontend registration form

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, api

I have an issue with frontend form submission with React Axios. Using WordPress API to create a user through the frontend registration form. The form has 3 fields username, email and password. Also, I have JWT plugin installed for the token authorisation. The current error is 400 bad request. And the catch error message is "Missing parameter(s): password"

```
const Register = ({ props }) => {

const [register, setRegister] = useState({
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    userCreated: false,
    loading: false,
    token: '',
    message: ''
   
})

const handleOnSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setRegister({ loading: true })
    console.log(register)

    const userData = { 
        username: e.target[0].value,
        email: e.target[2].value,
        password: e.target[4].value
        //role: 'Administrator'
    }

    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('token') 

    axios.post('http://localhost:8888/react/wp-json/wp/v2/users', userData, {

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
        }
    })

        .then(res => {
            setRegister({
                loading: false,
                userCreated: !!res.data.id, 
                message: res.data.id ? 'New user created' : '',
            })
            console.log(res)
        })
    

        .catch(err => {
            setRegister({
                loading: false,
                message: err.response.data.message,
            })
            console.log(err)
        })

}


const handleOnChange = e => {
    setRegister({ ...register, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    console.log(register)
}



const { password, username, email, loading, error } = useState()

return ( my form here )
```

Comment: What does `e.target` look like?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean?? @jmargolisvt

Comment: I means add it to your question.  The problem seems to be that e.target[4] does not exist.